# Display one object from fetched data undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm having a hard time trying to display the first element of an array for example. 
I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined` even if it's working with a console.log. Here is the code :

```
constructor() {
   super()
   this.state = {
      posts: []
    }

    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this)
}
```

```
async componentDidMount() {
   const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
   const response = await fetch(url);
   const data = await response.json();

   this.setState({
      posts: data
    })

   console.log(data);  //working
   console.log(this.state.posts) //working
   console.log(this.state.posts[0].title) //working
}
```

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="head-title"> { this.state.posts[0].title } </div>
        <div className="head-body"> { this.state.posts[0].body} </div>
    )
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Its because it rendered first and then your new data has been populated to state. As setState call after successful response. you need to add some flag like loading so that it does not render this jsx until its not set api values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this. In addition to my answer :

```
    class test extends Component{
    constructor() {
       super()
       this.state = {
          posts: [],
    loading :true
        }

        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this)
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
       const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
       const response = await fetch(url);
       const data = await response.json();

       this.setState({
          posts: data,
        loading:false
        })

       console.log(data);  //working
       console.log(this.state.posts) //working
       console.log(this.state.posts[0].title) //working
    }
    }
    render() {
    if(this.state.loading) return null;//Dont render component
        //or add ternary condition
        return (
            <div className="head-title"> { this.state.posts[0].title } </div>
            <div className="head-body"> { this.state.posts[0].body} </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was that!

Answer (score 0):

Your component will attempt to render `this.state.posts[0].title` while the request still hasn't finished and thus will throw an error.

Add a check to make sure your data exists for example like so:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="head-title"> { (this.state.posts.length > 0) ? this.state.posts[0].title : null } </div>
        <div className="head-body"> { (this.state.posts.length > 0) ? this.state.posts[0].body : null} </div>
    )
}
```